# Sending a push notification directly from the app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

Not too experienced with mobile development, but I wanted to know if this was possible.
After the user installs the app (android or ios), the app should at least once a day "wake-up" and show a push notification to the user.
Is this possible?

Comment: something like this makes sense (local notifications): https://www.joshmorony.com/getting-familiar-with-local-notifications-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I believe that you need setup a recurring alarm using AlarmManager. You also need to setup starting alarm service on device reboot. You can write a method that does what you want so it get executed when the alarm runs e.g. show notification. The following links should help you:

- [Repeat Alarm Example In Android Using AlarmManager](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)